# How can I see specific location on java desktop application?

Tags: java, google-maps-api

I want to see a desired lat/lon point on the google maps on my java desktop application. I made some search so I think google map API is something which I looking for. Am I right? and Is there any useful example for me? (I am totally beginner at google Map API for java)
And I would not to use Android.

Comment: Note that you may only use the free Google Maps API if your application is publicly accessible without charge: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=de#section_9_1 .

Comment: @ til_b Thanks for replay. I want to know if is there Google Maps API for java (not for Android)?

Comment: Have you googled at all? Googling for "google maps api java" finds https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/mapsengine/v1 , which says "yes, there is".

Comment: TNX @til_b it was useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use JavaFX for Java desktop applications whenever possible.
Here is a good example of Google maps API and JavaFX integration:

https://rterp.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/gmapsfx-add-google-maps-to-your-javafx-application/

This will give you an idea of how you can use it in your own project.

But if you need to embed and display Google Maps in your Java Desktop Swing application, then JxBrowser Java library is what you need.
Check this article for example:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/google-maps-java-swing